# ListView Scrolling error

Tags: android, listview, scroll, imageview

I have a custom `ListView` with an `ImageView`, `TextView` and a `CheckBox`.
This problem may seem ancient to some programmers but I really couldn't find a definitive solution. My problem is with the `ImageView`. When I scroll the images changes .

Some details are:

- I am not using a `RecyclerView`
- To maintain the state of `CheckBox` I am using `getTag` and `setTag` methods. And they are working fine.
- I am trying to implement a file explorer.
- I have provided a default image for almost all file types, including images.
- Inside `AsyncTask` I want to load thumbnails of images and videos and once they are loaded attach them to the corressponding `ImageView`. ----> this is the issue.

I am unable to maintain the position of `ImageView`. Even on scrolling the non image `ImageView`(i.e. which do not corresspond to the image or videos) are also losing their default images.

Here is my code of `getView` implemented inside the `ListAdapter` class:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        File file=new File(String.valueOf(filenames[position]));
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            img=R.drawable.folder;
        }

        else{
            img=getImage(filenames[position]);
        }


        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            viewHolder.iv= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(imageView);
            viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    myList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView1, viewHolder.tv);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.cb);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.iv);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.iv.getLayoutParams().height = 80;
        viewHolder.iv.getLayoutParams().width = 80;
        viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);
        final ViewHolder ViewHolder= viewHolder;

        ViewHolder.tv.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
        ViewHolder.cb.setChecked(myList.get(position).isSelected());
        viewHolder.iv.setImageResource(img);


        Log.v("this","viewHolderMT: "+String.valueOf(viewHolder)+" position: "+position);

        final View finalConvertView = convertView;




        myTask m=new myTask(position,viewHolder.iv);
        m.execute();

       return convertView;



    }
    class myTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Bitmap,Bitmap>{



        int pos;
        ImageView iv;
        public myTask(int pos,ImageView iv){
            this.pos=pos;
            this.iv=iv;
            iv.setTag(pos);
            //iv.setImageBitmap(null);

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Bitmap thumb=null;
            //Log.v("this","position: "+String.valueOf(position));

            if((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".jpeg")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".jpg")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".png")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".bmp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".gif")){

                thumb = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(filenames[pos])), 64, 64);
                //publishProgress(thumb);

                //Log.v("this","viewHolderDIB: "+String.valueOf(viewHolder)+"position: "+position);
                //Log.v("this","filenameDOI: "+String.valueOf(filenames[pos])+" positionDOI: "+String.valueOf(pos));
            }
            else if((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".mp4")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".mkv")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webm")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gpp")){
                thumb=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filenames[pos].getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                // Log.v("this","viewHolderDIB: "+String.valueOf(viewHolder)+"position: "+position);
               // publishProgress(thumb);

            }
            return thumb;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... thumb){


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap thumb){
            /*if(isCancelled()){
                return;
            }
*/
            if(thumb!=null && (Integer)iv.getTag()==this.pos) {
                if ((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".jpeg") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".jpg") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".png") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".bmp") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webp") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".gif")) {
                    //Log.v("this","filenameOPE: "+String.valueOf(filenames[pos])+" positionOPE: "+String.valueOf(pos));
                    iv.setImageBitmap(thumb);
                    //iv.setTag(pos);
                  //  Log.v("this", "In PU: " + String.valueOf(thumb));
                }
                //} else if ((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".mp4") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".mkv") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webm") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gp") || String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gpp")) {

                  //  iv.setImageBitmap(thumb);
                //}
                //Log.v("this ", "Tag: " + String.valueOf(pos));

            }





        }
    }
```

Here filenames is a File `array` containing the list of files which pass through the main activity into the list `adapter` class.

P.S. If you want I can also update the post with main activity. Thanks in advance. I a newbie so please co-operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add these two method inside your adapter and check

```
@Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {

   return getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

   return position;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer was too quick... It says 4 minutes remaining